# Convert Stream to byte[] c# for large files of 2GB

Tags: c#, stream, byte

Trying to convert Stream object to byte[] and using the below method for the same:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(System.IO.Stream input)
{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
}
```

However the input parameter "input" is for large file that is of 2 GB and hence the code does not get enter into while loop and hence does not convert it to byte array.

For smaller files it is working fine

Comment: I suspect you'll have a hard time creating an array with more than 2^31 elements. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Trying to download the large file using sharepoint 2010 - client object model. We have file of 2GB. So to downlaod it we used we the below code:FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, "thisFile");

System.IO.Stream stream = fileInfo.Stream;   Now our project requirement is that we want to return byte[] and not Stream object, hence trying to convert stream to byte[]

Comment: That "project requirement" sounds pretty ropy, to be honest. Have you checked that a byte array that large is feasible?

Comment: Yes verified that byte array is feasible till 2 gb

Comment: But "till" 2GB is fine already... what about *more than* 2GB? Have you tried creating a 3GB byte array?

Comment: I have not created more than 2gb byte array. But our maximum file size won't be more than 2gb hence that would be sufficient. Also initially have tried that byte array can upto 2gb only

Comment: Well then it should be fine with the code you've already got. To be honest, it's very confusing when you say "and hence the code does not get enter into while loop" - why would it not enter the while loop, if the file is 2GB?

Answer (score 1):

That's what a `Stream` is for.
You don't load the whole content into a `byte[]`, you read a small buffer from the `Stream` into memory and handle it, then dispose and read the next buffer.

If you still need to use a byte[]:

It seems like your app can't handle more than `2^32 Bytes` Memory, meaning it's **32bit**.
Try changing it to **64bit** (in Project Properties go to Build and disable `Prefer 32 bit`)

Comment: Changing the program to `Prefer 32 bit` does not make your program 64 bit, it just means you use 64 bit on 64 bit OSs. The program will still fail on 32 bit OSs. What you need to do is change from AnyCPU to x64 so the program can't run on 32 bit.

Comment: We fetch the data from SharePoint in the form of file.Stream. Our requirement is to fetch the content of stream in byte[]. As our project interface returns the byte array data. If there is any other easy way round then please help out

Answer (score 0):

Object limited below 32bit. (that is why all index using int)

how about use list contains byte array to deal entire data?

```
    public List<byte[]> ReadBytesList(string fileName)
    {
        List<byte[]> rawDataBytes= new List<byte[]>();
        byte[] buff;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,
                                       FileMode.Open,
                                       FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
        int arrayCount= (int)(numBytes / 2100000000); //2147483648 is max
        int arrayRest = (int)(numBytes % 2100000000);
        if(arrayCount>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
            {
                buff = br.ReadBytes(2100000000);
                rawDataBytes.Add(buff);
            }
            buff = br.ReadBytes(arrayRest);
            rawDataBytes.Add(buff);
        }
        else
        {
            buff = br.ReadBytes(arrayRest);
            rawDataBytes.Add(buff);
        }
        return rawDataBytes;
    }
```